# Joint probability function of the release number in which heads and tails appear

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

An honest coin is tossed 10 times. The following random variables are defined:

$X$  =  Number of the toss in which the first head occurs

$Y$ = Number of the toss in which the first tails occurs

What is the joint distribution of (X,Y)? I think they are independent, but I'm not sure, if anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the same coin, the first toss is either heads or tails. Hence, either $X=1$ or $Y=1$, so if $X > 1$ we know $Y = 1$ and vice versa. So we are clearly not independent, since $X=1$ causes $Y > 1$.

Also, it is not possible for $X> 1$ and $Y > 1$ (because our first flip must be either heads or tails), so all of those have probability zero. Finally, If $Y = 1$, $X = x$ has the same probability as $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$, since we would have the exact same event in both scenarios
(being $TTT\ldots H$). This also occurs for $Y$. Putting it all together, we obtain:

$$\mathbb{P}(X= x, Y = y) = f_{XY}(x, y) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{P}(X = x) & \text{if }X = x > 1, Y = 1 \\\mathbb{P}(Y = y) & \text{if } X = 1, Y = y > 1 \\ 0 & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
And then you would calculate $\mathbb{P}(X = x)$ trivially. Let me know if you have any additional questions. Also, this is assuming that we have some mechanism of dealing with no heads or no tails in ten flips.

Comment: ooh Thank you! Now I see a clear dependence between them. Greetings!